# How to tell vim to behave the same for file extension .in and .mako

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I noticed Vim will choose the correct syntax when I open a file that ends with `.c.in` or `.pl.in`.

I would like to tell Vim to behave the same with extensions like `.c.mako` or `.pl.mako`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use autocommands in your .vimrc like

`au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.c.mako setf c`

This will make all `*.c.mako` files behave like `*.c` files.

Make an analogous for `*.pl.mako`

If you genenerally want `*.any.mako` to behave like `*.any` then you can use this autocommand:

`au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.mako exe "doau filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(expand("<afile>:r"))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to globally associate a filename extension with a setting for the 'filetype' option when the file is opened. There are a few ways to do this. One way is described by @Naumann in another answer. Let's look at two other ways. These don't involve your vimrc file and are the recommended approaches per `:help new-filetype` (which I encourage you to read!)

With the first option you create a file, let's call it `perlmako.vim`, in `~/.vim/ftdetect` (Unix) or `$USERPROFILE\vimfiles\ftdetect` (Win) and add a line like either of these:

*Method A:*

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl.mako set filetype=perl
```

*Method B:*

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl.mako setfiletype perl
```

The difference between the two is that Method A always overrides the filetype while Method B only works if no filetype has been detected yet for that extension.

---

For the second option, create a file named `filetype.vim` in `~/.vim` (Unix) or `$USERPROFILE\vimfiles` (Win). Then add the following:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
    finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.pl.mako setfiletype perl
augroup END
```

You can add multiple `setfiletype` lines for whatever extensions you want. One important point about this method from Vim help:

> Your filetype.vim will be sourced before the default FileType
> autocommands have been installed. Your autocommands will match first,
> and the ":setfiletype" command will make sure that no other
> autocommands will set 'filetype' after this.